# Adwords conversion threw google analytics with react

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-ads-api, implicit-conversion, web-traffic

I am using Google Ads to get some traffic to my website.

I am tracking the conversions through Google Analytics

[image: Adwords]

I can see my conversions on Google Analytics, but Google Ads is not counting any conversion

[image: Analytics]

Here the goal configuration

[image: Goal 1]
[image: Goal 2]

The 36 conversions Which I have from Google are traffic through Google Ads and not organic. But on my Google Ads dashboard, I have 0 conversions.

The website is built with react, which could be a little tricky sometimes with tags, and Google Analytics is loaded through Google Tag Manager. I do not think the problem is coming from GTM configuration as we do have the conversions on Google Analytics

[image: GTM]

Comment: From what I understand you are importing a goal from Google Analytics into Google Ads. Can you share the configuration of this goal in your question? Also Source Google can be google search or google ads.

Comment: Hi @SimonBreton The configuration is the first image

Comment: the first image is the configuration of the conversion in Google Ads not the configuration of the goal in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem with the site in React is that when the user lands from an ads and then visits a second page, the gclid parameter is lost but the google.com referrer is kept. So on the second page a new session will be generated and that results from organic traffic. So if the user converts it will be organic instead of paid.

Try to see this article to apply a solution: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/persist-campaign-data-landing-page/